# How can I name Button object as what my String variable brings

Tags: java, swing

```
public void createButton(int x, int y, String s) {
    try {
        JButton btn1 = new JButton();
        jPanel1.add(btn1);
        btn1.setLocation(x, y);
        btn1.setSize(50, 50);
        btn1.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

That is the method which I use to create random buttons. But I can't give the button a name manually every time. I want name button object with what my String variable contains.

Comment: pass String `s` to the constructor of JButton.

Comment: Where i can write s ?

Comment: Do not post a picture of your code.  Copy the actual code into your question, with each line indented by four spaces so it will appear as a formatted block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment on another answer:

> I don t want change button name.i want button variable name (in this case it is btn1) change to what string s brings.

Java is not designed that way, if you want to keep a reference for each `JButton` you can create an array:

```
JButton buttonsArray[] = new JButton[5]; //Or any amount of buttons
```

Then use them like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttonsArray.length; i++) {
    buttonsArray[i] = createButton(text[i]);
}
```

Where `text[i]` is a `String` array where you have all the text for your `JButton`s

Or probably with an `ArrayList` of `JButton`:

```
ArrayList <JButton> buttonsList = new ArrayList <JButton>();
```

And then use it like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    JButton button = createButton(text[i]);
    buttonList.add(button);
}
```

Then you can select each button with:

```
buttonArray[i].setText("Hello"); //Or whatever method you want to call
buttonList.get(i).setText("Hello");
jPanel1.add(buttonsArray[i]);
jPanel1.add(buttonsList.get(i));
```

Now your `createButton()` method should look like this:

```
public JButton createButton(String s) {
    JButton btn1 = new JButton(s);
    //Add more code here
    return btn1;
}
```

In this question you can see an similar example using an array of `JRadioButton`

---

## IMPORTANT NOTE

Finally I need to add this to my answer, don't set location /bounds of each `JComponent` manually instead use a proper [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) that does the job for you and [Empty Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) to create space between them if needed.

I bet you're using a `null` layout and while that might seem like the best and easiest way to create a GUI, the more GUIs you create, you're gonna get more errors due to this and more troubles trying to maintain it.

See: [Null layout is evil](http://www.leepoint.net/GUI/layouts/nulllayout.html) and [Why is it frowned upon to use a null layout in swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing).

I hope that helps

Comment: Thank you a looooooot for your help my friend.that is exatelly what i need :)

Comment: @Silver I'm glad it helped, don't forget to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer then :)

Answer (score 2):

```
public void createButton(int x, int y, String s) {
    try {
        JButton btn1 = new JButton(s);
        jPanel1.add(btn1);
        btn1.setLocation(x, y);
        btn1.setSize(50, 50);
        btn1.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

The constructor `JButton(text)` internally calls `setText(text)`. So `btn1.setText(text)` later on would be the same. From the code:

```
/**
 * Creates a button with initial text and an icon.
 *
 * @param text  the text of the button
 * @param icon  the Icon image to display on the button
 */
public JButton(String text, Icon icon) {
    // Create the model
    setModel(new DefaultButtonModel());

    // initialize
    init(text, icon);
}
```

Keep in mind: `setText()` and `setName()` are not the same thing!

Comment: I don t want change button name.i want button variable name (in this case it is btn1) change to what string s brings.